# Powershell building broken paths

Tags: powershell

I have a script being run via scheduled task. Occasionally when the script runs it outputs a broken path. The path should be a folder, named with the current date, however sometimes this path is not a folder but instead a file, type '28 File'. I have attached an image of the broken path below.

The script will only build this path if it does not exist, per the `Test-Path` shown below. I can only replicate the error if a user deletes the `$dailyLocal` folder, when the next pass of the script tries to rebuild the path, we see the broken path.

Are there any additional parameters I can put in place to prevent this? Does anyone even understand the error or what '28 File' is?

EDIT: The 28 is from the date format, Powershell thinks I am asking to build a file with extension .28, I have already specified the new path should be a folder. Are there any other measures I can take to specify this as a folder?

```
#name variables
$bay = 'X1'
$hotFolder = 'C:\Hot_Folder'
$uploadArchive = 'C:\Hot_Folder\Archive'

$today = get-date -Format yyyy.MM.dd
$dailyServer = "\\server\$today $bay"
$dailyLocal = "$uploadArchive\$today $bay"

#build local archive and server archive path for date and bay (test if exists first)
if(!((Test-Path -Path $dailyServer -PathType Container) -or (Test-Path -Path $dailyLocal -PathType Container))){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $dailyServer, $dailyLocal
}

#copy to server archive, then move to local archive
$uploadImages = GCI $hotFolder -Filter *.jpg
    foreach ($image in $uploadImages){
        Write-Host "this is the new valid image" $image -ForegroundColor Green
            Copy-Item $image.FullName -Destination $dailyServer -Force
                Move-Item $image.FullName -Destination $dailyLocal -Force
                                           
}
```

[image]

Comment: "28 File" is just what Windows Explorer shows when it encounters a file with `.28` at the end - it assumes `.28` is the file extension, and given that no registered file types match the extension it just says "28 File", the samw way you might say an image is a "JPEG file". Can you show us the whole thing? `New-Item` doesn't usually write 6 megabytes of arbitrary data to disk out of nowhere :)

Comment: I don’t see any error or “broken path”

Comment: Wow, not sure how i missed this, it is identifying the date as a file extension... duh.

I'm not able to change the date formatting at this time, any ideas on how to ensure the created path is a folder? I assumed identifying the `new-item` as `-Itemtype directory` would be sufficient but apparently not

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the folder is being built so a few .JPGs can be moved into it. The 6 MB is prob from those two files, they are about 3 MB each.

Comment: There's nothing in the code sample you've provided that would explain the behavior described. I'm gonna ask again: can you show us the whole thing? :)

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks for your vigilance. I found a work around that i'll use but will post the full thing for any additional learning opportunities.

The server archive was fine, but the local archive was experiencing the aforementioned issue. The difference was that the server archive folder ended with the computer bay number instead of ending in .28 (the date). I adopted the same naming convention on local archive and the problem seems to be resolved.